# Why is the validation accuracy low even though I'm using a pretrained model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-classification, pre-trained-model, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to classify 10 species of birds on google colab using a pretrained model from tensorflow hub which has been trained on 964 species of birds. But when I train it, the accuracy isn't as high as I thought it would be. The loss is also considerably high. I'm not sure if I've done something wrong when I imported the model. For some reason when I view model.summary(), the # of parameters for the KerasLayer shows as 0. Why is that? I have attached all my code below.

```
   import numpy as np
   import tensorflow as tf
   from tensorflow import keras
   from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  from google.colab import drive
  drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount=True)
  dataset_path = '/content/gdrive/MyDrive/images/'


  image_size = (224,224)
  batch_size = 10

  train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, 
                               rotation_range=15,
                               zoom_range = (0.95,0.95),
                               width_shift_range=0.1,
                               height_shift_range=0.1,
                               validation_split=0.2,
                               dtype = tf.float32,
                              )

  validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2, dtype = 
  tf.float32,)

  train_batches = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
  dataset_path,
  target_size = image_size,
  batch_size = batch_size,
  color_mode='rgb',
  class_mode = 'categorical',
  shuffle = True,
  seed = 123,
  subset = 'training', )

  validation_batches = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
  dataset_path,
  target_size = image_size,
  batch_size = batch_size,
  color_mode='rgb',
  class_mode = 'categorical',
  shuffle = True,
  seed = 123,
  subset = 'validation', )

  test_batches = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
  dataset_path,
  target_size = image_size,
  batch_size = batch_size,
  color_mode='rgb',
  class_mode = 'categorical',
  shuffle = True,
  seed = 123,
  subset = 'validation', )

  from keras import layers
  import tensorflow_hub as hub


 url = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/aiy/vision/classifier/birds_V1/1'
 base_model = hub.KerasLayer(url, input_shape=(224, 224, 3), trainable=False)

 num_of_birds = 10

 model = tf.keras.Sequential([
 base_model,
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_of_birds, activation='softmax'),
  ])

 model.summary()
```

[image: model summary]

When I train the model on a high number of epochs, the accuracy actually drops lower. Therefore I have only trained it for one epoch. But even then I'm not satisfied with the accuracy. I want it to be higher. Can somebody please tell me what I've done wrong?
[image: training and testing]

Answer (score 0):

You can try data argumentation layer in your model for making your training data more diverse and make sure your bird images are well-cropped. Example code below.

```
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential([
  preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
  preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2),
  preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.2),
  preprocessing.RandomHeight(0.2),
  preprocessing.RandomWidth(0.2),
], name ="data_augmentation")
```

You can also try [model fine tuning](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-classification-transfer-learning-and-fine-tuning-using-tensorflow-a791baf9dbf3) to improve model's prediction performance.

model.summary() shows the # of parameters for the KerasLayer shows as 0 because you have loaded the base model with `trainable = False` so the base_model parameters are freezed. You can also turn trainable parameter to True and the base model layers will be updated while training.